# Adaptive Layout - Error With Uninstalled View - Xcode

Tags: xcode, autolayout

In IB I built a view. Within that view there's a particular subview which I only want to have show on the iPad when it's regular/regular. My understanding from online guides is that I can do that by checking the "Installed" boxes accordingly:

[image: uninstalled View - Autolayout]

However, this caused an error saying "Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration...". But if I'm in R/R and ALL my views are showing, how is that even possible?

**Troubleshooting 1**

To try to solve it, for the compact/compact and compact/regular I uninstalled the constraints too!

[image: uninstalled constraints]

**Troubleshooting 2**

I found a tutorial showing how to right click that warning message and find the actual constraint in the log. I copy/pasted the constraint ID into the Find bar and it was my leading-to-superview constraint. I uninstalled that constraint for everything but R/R yet I still get the error.

**Question**

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing "strange" here. If a view is present only in `wRhR`, obviously any constraint involving that view had better be present only in `wRhR`. A constraint without one of the views to which it refers — *that* would be strange!

As for the second part of your question, you have given no information that would allow anyone to assist you. You can easily look at the storyboard and it will tell you what view now needs constraints, and you will have to supply them (probably just in the `wRhR` case).

Comment: Thanks Matt. What I was saying was more that I found it odd seeing the warning appear in both R/R and others (wR/hC, etc). I had already found a tutorial helping me ID the specific constraint but that didn't help. I've added more detail to my question, in case that helps.

Comment: You are asking: "But if I'm in R/R and ALL my views are showing, how is that even possible". But what if you're _not_ in R/R? Then clearly it makes no sense to have the view be absent but the constraint(s) be present.

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying and you're right. I just fixed it. Is this dumb enough that I should just delete the question? Or just choose correct and leave it?

Comment: Totally up to you! I'm happy if I've helped straighten things out.